# how to get custom added variable products attribute and attribute terms using woocommerce rest api v3

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

I am trying to get custom added attributes and its terms of a variable product using woocommerce rest API [here is the value that i want from woocommerce rest api](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bm4Ka.png). But i dont find any woocommerce rest api documentation of getting custom attribute and attribute terms of variable product. thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following

1.`get_post_meta` to get the product attributes

```
$attr = get_post_meta( 123, '_product_attributes' ); // replace 123 with the actual product id 
print_r( $attr );
```

2.Or you can create a product object and then using the `get_attributes` method

```
$p = new WC_Product( 123 ); // // replace 123 with the actual product id 
print_r( $p->get_attributes() );
```